# Grunt/NodeJs - Call ant command as a spawn process on windows environment

Tags: node.js, ant, gruntjs, spawn

In a grunt build process on a windows environment I'd like to call two ant command as spawn processes to be able to track output.

It goes like follow :

```
    grunt.registerTask('app-clean', 'Cleaning tasks', function() {
        var done = this.async();

        if (context.device.platform === 'android' || context.device.platform === 'all') {
            spawnProcess('ant', ['clean'], {
                cwd: path.resolve(context.android)
            }, done);
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('app-build', 'Building tasks', function() {
        var done = this.async();

        if (context.device.platform === 'android' || context.device.platform === 'all') {
            spawnProcess('ant', ['release'], {
                cwd: path.resolve(context.android)
            }, done);
        }
    });

    // Helper function to execute and log out child process
    // TODO: implement a better success/error callback
    var spawnProcess = function(command, args, options, callback) {
        var process = spawn(command, args, options),
            err = false;

        process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            grunt.log.write(data);
        });

        process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            err = true;
            grunt.log.errorlns(data);
        });

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            process.on('exit', function() {
                if (!err) {
                    return callback();
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

The `grunt build` using those tasks is then triggered by comand line step in ***Team City***.

Both commands return a `Fatal error: spawn ENOENT`.

Answer (score 1):

Windows requires a file extension for commands, such as `.cmd`, `.exe`, `.bat` appended to the command. I *think* ant supplies an `ant.cmd` in which case you would do:

```
var antCmd = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'ant.cmd' : 'ant';
```

To make it cross platform.

Comment: It seems to work using exec instead of spawn, but I'm not sure which one would be ideal. ```exec``` works with no environment distinction and also give the output as expected. I'll update my question with this version in a few.

Comment: The only significant difference between exec and spawn is what they return. `spawn` will give you a stream where `exec` gives you a buffer. `Fatal error: spawn ENOENT` means the command you're trying to run does not exist and almost always on Windows, assuming the command does exist, it means it wants an extension.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following grunt script to do shell commands and kick off an ant process as well.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell

Comment: Thanks, it looks like Sindresorhus is also using ```exec``` there in ```shell.js``` so I'm more confident in using my ```exec``` solution for now, but it seems a good alternative to do pretty much the same thing my custom function do in a "config only" way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing the spawn process by an exec one fixed it, but both other answers also work.

```
var execProcess = function(command, options, callback) {
        var process = exec(command, options),
            err = false;

        process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            grunt.log.write(data);
        });

        process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            err = true;
            grunt.log.errorlns(data);
        });

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            process.on('exit', function() {
                if (!err) {
                    return callback();
                }
            });
        }
};

execProcess('ant release', { cwd: path.resolve(context.android) }, done);
```

***Note that the exec process take one less argument.***